# Java: make a function return positive integer not negative one

Tags: java, arrays, math, integer

as I was coding this project for fun, I got stuck myself on getting the output that I want: getting the positive element out of the input, 2 and -2.

To put it more simply, I want the output to be positive 2 not negative 2.

The general idea of this is getting the closest element to Zero. But here, I'm assuming that the positive one is closer to 0.

Hope any of you can answer my question. Personally I want to become better at Java so that I can help newbie like myself now, later in the future. Anyways, thank you, in advance.

```
  static int getClosestToZero(int[] array) {
    int num = array[0];
    int absNum = Math.abs(num);
    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; ++i) {
        int newAbs = Math.abs(array[i]);
        if(newAbs < absNum) {
            absNum = newAbs;
            num = array[i];

            }
        }

    return num;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] myArray = {-2, 2};

            System.out.println(getClosestToZero(myArray));
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't last line in `if` be `num = newAbs;`?

Comment: Should be >=, not <.....line 6

Comment: @MarounMaroun Huge thanks to both of you!

Comment: What do you want to be returned in case of `{2, -1}`?

Comment: @DreamInCode Those comments are not exactly correct. You do not want `num = newAbs`, {-3,-2} would return 2. And changing `<` to `>=` would make you look for the number further from 0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
static int getClosestToZero(int[] array)
{
    int num = array[0];
    int absNum = Math.abs(num);
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; ++i)
    {
        int newAbs = Math.abs(array[i]);
        if (newAbs < absNum)
        {
            absNum = newAbs;
            num = array[i];

        }else if(newAbs == absNum && array[i]>=0)//if equals and the current is positive, then take it
        {
                num = array[i];
        }
    }

    return num;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you check if the value is closer to zero than the current closest value, simply use Math.abs() to make get the absolute value and check if it matches current closest. If they match, ignore it and continue iterating.

Comment: This is exactly what OP's current code does.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the condition:

```
if (newAbs < absNum || (newAbs == absNum && array[i] > num)) {
```

it will replace the negative value with the *same* positive if there is any.